# How to find the general solution to this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= (1+x)y+xy^{2}$$

The equation can be formatted to a Bernoulli equation, in the form

$$\frac{dy}{dx}-(1+x)y = xy^{2}$$

However, attempting this any further leads to integrating $$-xe^{(x+\frac{x^{2}}{2})}$$ which leads me to believe I am not attempting this equation correctly.

Comment: Attempting *what* any further? (You should include any other relevant work you did in your question)

Comment: Finding the general solution in the form of y =

Comment: That integral is slightly worse: the exponent is negative all through. Anyway, can't you leave the solution with and integral or whatever? Of course you will need then, for the original $\;y\;$ , to have an integral of an integral. Not pretty...

Comment: Wolfram says the soln can be expressed in terms of the imaginary error function.

Answer (score 2):

The differential equation has the form $y'+a(x)y=b(x)y^{\alpha}$ which is Bernoulli as you said. The standard method of solution is to make the substitution $\phi=y^{1-\alpha}$.

We have $$y'-(1+x)y=xy^{2}\tag{1}$$
Setting $\phi=y^{1-2}=y^{-1}$ then $\phi'=-y^{-2}y'$ and $(1)$ can be written as
$$\phi'+(x+1)\phi=-x \tag{2}$$
which is a linear differential equation and can be solved using integrating factor.

Let the integrating factor $\mu(x)=e^{\int (x+1)\, dx}=e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}+x }$ and then multiply both sides of $(2)$ by $\mu(x)$ we have
$$e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}+x}\left(\phi'+(x+1)\phi \right) =-xe^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}+x}$$
that can be written as
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\phi e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}+x} \right)=-xe^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}+x}\tag{3}$$
Integrating $(3)$ we have
$$e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}+x}\phi=\int -x e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}+x}\, dx+C.$$
Since $\phi=y^{-1}$, then we have the integral representation solution
$$y^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}+x}}\left( \int-x e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}+x}\, dx+C\right).$$
That is,
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}+x}}\left( \int-x e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}+x}\, dx+C\right)}$$
Using the fact ${\rm erf}(z)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{z}e^{-t^{2}}\, dt$, and ${\rm erfi}(z)=-i {\rm erf}(iz)$ with $i$ the imaginary unity we can show that
$$\int -xe^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}+x}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2e}}{\rm erfi}\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)-e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}+x}$$
Hence the general solution can be written as
$$y(x)=\frac{-2e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}+x}}{2e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}+x}-\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{e}} {\rm erfi}\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+C}$$

Comment: Solution with explicit start value $y_0$:
$$y(x)\to-\frac{2 e^{\frac{1}{2} x (x+2)} y_{0}}{y_{0} \left(\sqrt{\frac{2 \pi }{e}} \text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+2 e^{\frac{1}{2} x (x+2)}-2\right)-\sqrt{\frac{2 \pi }{e}} y_{0} \text{erfi}\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-2}$$
with $y(0)=y_0$

Answer (score 0):

You could put the ODE into the Bernoulli formula, then divide by $-y^{2}$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}y}{\operatorname{d}x} = \left( 1 + x \right) \cdot y + x \cdot y^{2} &\Leftrightarrow \frac{\operatorname{d}y}{\operatorname{d}x} - \left( 1 + x \right) \cdot y = x \cdot y^{2}\\
\frac{\operatorname{d}y}{\operatorname{d}x} - \left( 1 + x \right) \cdot y = x \cdot y^{2} &\Leftrightarrow -\frac{\frac{\operatorname{d}y}{\operatorname{d}x}}{y^{2}} + \frac{\left( 1 + x \right)}{y} = -x\\
\end{align*}
$$

From here you can work well with the classic substitution $u = y^{-1}$ for this type of ODE:
$$
\begin{align*}
-\frac{\frac{\operatorname{d}y}{\operatorname{d}x}}{y^{2}} + \frac{\left( 1 + x \right)}{y} = -x &\Leftrightarrow \frac{\operatorname{d}u}{\operatorname{d}x} + \left( 1 + x \right) \cdot u = -x\\
\end{align*}
$$

With this you have brought your ODE into the form of a linear ODE of order 1, which you can now do with the classic solution methods such as integrating factor (multiplying the ODE by $\exp\left( \int_{0}^{x} x + 1 \operatorname{d}x \right)$ aka $\exp\left( \frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{2} + x \right)$) or the separation of variables method (using the substitution $u = v \cdot w$).

For example, with the integrating factor method, you could continue like this:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}u}{\operatorname{d}x} + \left( 1 + x \right) \cdot u = -x &\Leftrightarrow \exp\left( \frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{2} + x \right) \cdot \left( \frac{\operatorname{d}u}{\operatorname{d}x} + \left( 1 + x \right) \cdot u \right) = -\exp\left( \frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{2} + x \right) \cdot x\\
&\Leftrightarrow \frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}x}\left( \exp\left( \frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{2} + x \right) \cdot u \right) = -\exp\left( \frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{2} + x \right) \cdot x\\
\end{align*}
$$

The next step would be integration by $x$ of both sides, which leads to the problem that there is no closed form as a solution. From here you could, for example, work with rows or special functions. I would work with [hypergeometric functions $\operatorname{_{1}F_{1}}\left( a;\, b;\, z \right)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) (also known as Kummer's function or confluent hypergeometric function):
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}x}\left( \exp\left( \frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{2} + x \right) \cdot u \right) &= -\exp\left( \frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{2} + x \right) \cdot x\\
\exp\left( \frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{2} + x \right) \cdot u &= \int -\exp\left( \frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{2} + x \right) \cdot x \operatorname{d}x\\
\exp\left( \frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{2} + x \right) \cdot u &= \left( x + 1 \right) \cdot \operatorname{_{1}F_{1}}\left( \frac{1}{2};\, \frac{3}{2};\, \frac{\left( x + 1 \right)^{2}}{2} \right) - \exp\left( \frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{2} + x \right) + c_{1}\\
u &= \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{2} - x \right) \cdot \left( x + 1 \right) \cdot \operatorname{_{1}F_{1}}\left( \frac{1}{2};\, \frac{3}{2};\, \frac{\left( x + 1 \right)^{2}}{2} \right) + \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{2} - x \right) \cdot c_{1} - 1\\
\end{align*}
$$

As @gpmath noted:
You can write $\left( x + 1 \right) \cdot \operatorname{_{1}F_{1}}\left( \frac{1}{2};\, \frac{3}{2};\, \frac{\left( x + 1 \right)^{2}}{2} \right)$ in terms of error functions via [this formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html) like this:
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{erfi}\left( z \right) &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \cdot z \cdot \operatorname{_{1}F_{1}}\left( \frac{1}{2};\, \frac{3}{2};\, z^{2} \right)\\
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \cdot \operatorname{erfi}\left( z \right) &= z \cdot \operatorname{_{1}F_{1}}\left( \frac{1}{2};\, \frac{3}{2};\, z^{2} \right)\\
z^{2} &:= \frac{\left( x + 1 \right)^{2}}{2}\\
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \cdot \operatorname{erfi}\left( \frac{x + 1}{\sqrt{2}} \right) &= \frac{x + 1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot \operatorname{_{1}F_{1}}\left( \frac{1}{2};\, \frac{3}{2};\, \frac{\left( x + 1 \right)^{2}}{2} \right)\\
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot \operatorname{erfi}\left( \frac{x + 1}{\sqrt{2}} \right) &= \left( x + 1 \right) \cdot \operatorname{_{1}F_{1}}\left( \frac{1}{2};\, \frac{3}{2};\, \frac{\left( x + 1 \right)^{2}}{2} \right)\\
\\
u &= \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{2} - x \right) \cdot \left( x + 1 \right) \cdot \operatorname{_{1}F_{1}}\left( \frac{1}{2};\, \frac{3}{2};\, \frac{\left( x + 1 \right)^{2}}{2} \right) + \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{2} - x \right) \cdot c_{1} - 1\\
u &= \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{2} - x \right) \cdot \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot \operatorname{erfi}\left( \frac{x + 1}{\sqrt{2}} \right) + \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{2} - x \right) \cdot c_{1} - 1\\
\end{align*}
$$

Now you can resubstitute $u = y^{-1}$:
$$
\begin{align*}
y^{-1} &= \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{2} - x \right) \cdot \left( x + 1 \right) \cdot \operatorname{_{1}F_{1}}\left( \frac{1}{2};\, \frac{3}{2};\, \frac{\left( x + 1 \right)^{2}}{2} \right) + \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{2} - x \right) \cdot c_{1} - 1\\
y &= \frac{1}{\exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{2} - x \right) \cdot \left( x + 1 \right) \cdot \operatorname{_{1}F_{1}}\left( \frac{1}{2};\, \frac{3}{2};\, \frac{\left( x + 1 \right)^{2}}{2} \right) + \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{2} - x \right) \cdot c_{1} - 1}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Since the hypergeometric functions usually have very close relationships to other functions, you could now exchange this function with an equivalent function that you are very familiar with ([see here for examples](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/27/01/)).
Aother useful relation that wolfram doesn't show include: $\operatorname{_{1}F_{1}}\left( a;\, a + 1;\, z \right) = a \cdot \left( -z \right)^{-a} \cdot \gamma\left(a,\, -z \right)$ where $\gamma\left(a,\, z \right)$ is the [incomplete gamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html). But there are many other relations like relation to [Bessel functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunction.html), [error function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html), [Hermite polynomial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitePolynomial.html), [Laguerre polynomial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaguerrePolynomial.html), ...

Comment: Unfortenately your solution with $\operatorname{_{1}F_{1}}$ doesn't solve the ODE $\frac{dy}{dx}= (1+x)y+xy^{2}$.

Comment: Your transformed ODE $u'(x)+(x+1) u(x)=-x$
has the correct solution
$$u(x)\to \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} (x+1)^2} \text{erfi}\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+c_1 e^{-\frac{1}{2} x (x+2)}-1$$

Comment: @gpmath Yeah. You're right. I made a mistake when calculating the hypergeometric function. I corrected it and checked it with relation to error function and solution you mentioned. Thanks for the comment.